# spring boot maven plugin build-image is not working

Tags: spring-boot, docker, buildpack

I created demo project from start.spring.io with spring boot version 3.0.1 and java version 17.

I tried to execute below command on terminal to build Docker image

`mvn spring-boot:build-image -Dspring-boot.build-image.imageName=testtesttest`

It resulted in error

```
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_THREAD_COUNT        250                                                          the number of threads in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS                                                                        the JVM launch flags
[INFO]     [creator]         Using Java version 18 extracted from MANIFEST.MF
[INFO]     [creator]       No valid JRE available, providing matching JDK instead. Using a JDK at runtime has security implications.
[INFO]     [creator]        : Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]       Warning: Dependency has no SHA256. Skipping cache.
[INFO]     [creator]         Downloading from 
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to invoke layer creator
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to get dependency 
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to download 
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to request 
[INFO]     [creator]     Get "": unsupported protocol scheme ""
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  14.756 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-01-02T15:18:19+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.1:build-image (default-cli) on project demo: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.1:build-image failed: Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 51 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

I am using openjdk (version "18.0.2" 2022-07-19) on mac. Not able to figure it out. Can you please help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the default image builder doesn't yet support Mac M1 processor. I had to add an alternative builder for maven plugin in my pom.xml as shown below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <image>
            <builder>dashaun/builder:tiny</builder>
        </image>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: The error above is a metadata problem but it's not clear why that's happening and you'd need to provide more info to figure that out. It's unlikely that you've directly addressed the issue by changing the builder, but if this works around the problem then great. You are correct that the Paketo builders do not presently support non-X86_64 hardware. The builder you've referenced is a community-managed builder that does support x86_64 & ARM64. Feel free to upvote https://github.com/orgs/paketo-buildpacks/discussions/58#discussioncomment-4345153 which will help prioritize official ARM64 support.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin may be trying to download a JDK / JRE that is not (anymore) provided by the build-image tools (see [GitHub issue](https://github.com/orgs/paketo-buildpacks/discussions/44)).

I fixed the issue in my setup by using JDK 17 instead. This is an LTS release of Java and thus longer maintained by the build-image tools.

After a clean build with the LTS Java version, it is working now and the output changed:

```
[INFO]     [creator]         Using Java version 17 extracted from MANIFEST.MF
[INFO]     [creator]         BellSoft Liberica JRE 17.0.7: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Downloading from https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/...
```